# Is there a way to perform atomic operations on a non-atomic object?

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic, stdatomic

I have a `struct` that contains an integer (say `int m_ref`) denoting an internal reference count.

In order to maintain C compatibility I can't change the type to `std::atomic<int>`: the `struct` may only contain plain old data.

However, I want to adjust my code to exploit the atomic features now in C++11; namely I need to accomplish:

```
++m_ref;
```

and

```
--m_ref;
```

as atomic operations. I'm currently using assembler (Intel bus locks) to do this but that code is hardly portable and I'm keen to remove it now that C++ offers a standard construct.

Somehow I need to get to 'under the hood' and do what `atomic<T>` does but without the overhead of creating an atomic type: I fear that attaching m_ref to `atomic<T>` will degrade performance.

I suspect this is quite standard and I'm missing something simple here.

Comment: Note that C11 introduced atomic types too, semantics should be the same as in C++11.

Comment: You'll probably find your fear is unwarranted. Unless you are doing something nasty like "sometimes m_ref is atomic, some times not", you should get identical results, zero overhead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With atomic_ref since C++20, you can do it like this:

```
#include <atomic>

void add(int& a)
{
    std::atomic_ref(a).fetch_add(1);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You cannot use atomic operations on a non-atomic type in C++11. You must use `std::atomic<int>` or `std::atomic_int` to get atomic operations on an integer. Casting an `int` to `std::atomic<int>` is undefined behaviour.

If you have a C11 compiler as well as a C++11 compiler then you can use `atomic_int` in both cases (with a suitable `using` declaration for C++). If the compilers are compatible then everything will "just work".